# Atbeacon onNonBeaconLeScan not called Android 10

Tags: android, altbeacon

I use Altbeacon "onNonBeaconLeScan" method to scan nonbeacon device. It scan Android 7.0 but it doesn't scan Android 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Altbeacon stopped working on Android10 and didEnterRegion does not get called at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58059097/altbeacon-stopped-working-on-android10-and-didenterregion-does-not-get-called-at)

Comment: @Peter I can scan beacon Android 10 beacuse targetSdkVersion 28. My problem is onNonBeaconLeScan function called in Android 7.0 but not called in Android 10.0

Comment: @uyarc, starting with Android 10, scan filters must be used in the background which may limit background detections to beacon advertisements matching the filter on Samsung phones.